# Convert a data.frame into a list of characters based on one of the column of the dataframe, which contains multiple characters, with R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I need to convert a data.frame into a list of characters based on one of the column of the dataframe. One of the colmuns conatins multiple categories inside of it.

It is similar to a previous question I asked ([Convert a data.frame into a list of characters based on one of the column of the dataframe with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346815/convert-a-data-frame-into-a-list-of-characters-based-on-one-of-the-column-of-the/61351780#61351780)), but more complex this time.

Starting from a data.frame of two colums, the first one contains uniques values of compounds names, while the other contains compound type categories, that are not unique. Example from this data frame:

```
`x <- structure(list(Compound_name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Compound_type = c("Inhibitor_A, Inhibitor_B", "Inhibitor_B", "Inhibitor_A, Inhibitor_C, Inhibitor_D", "Inhibitor_C", "Inhibitor_B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))`
```

I would like to get a list that looks like this:

```
Inhibitor_A   'A' 'C'
Inhibitor_B   'A' 'B' 'E'
Inhibitor_C   'C' 'D'
Inhibitor_D   'C'
```

I usually do it with `split` function, but as I have multiple categories in each Compound name, I don't know how to easly get to the result.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
x %>%
 separate_rows(Compound_type, sep = ", ") %>%
 group_by(Compound_type) %>%
 summarise(Compound_name = list(Compound_name))

  Compound_type Compound_name
  <chr>         <list>       
1 Inhibitor_A   <chr [2]>    
2 Inhibitor_B   <chr [3]>    
3 Inhibitor_C   <chr [2]>    
4 Inhibitor_D   <chr [1]>
```

Comment: Instead of `summarise(Compound_name = list(Compound_name))` I suggest `summarise(Compound_name = paste(Compound_name, collapse= " "))`

Comment: @Martin Gal the OP is specifically asking for a list. Using `paste()`, you get a character vector.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` with `strsplit`

```
with(stack(setNames(strsplit(x$Compound_type, ",\\s*"),
        x$Compound_name)), split(as.character(ind), values))
```